# How to break the line in a if-statement in Fortran 77?

Tags: fortran, fortran77

how can i break the line in a if-statement and go on in a new line with my condition in an example like this?

```
IF((TEMP_PT.GT.TEMP_EVAP.
&  AND.TFIELD(A+1,B).LT.TEMP_EVAP).OR.   
&  ((TEMP_PT.GT.TEMP_MELT.AND.TEMP_PT.LT.TEMP_EVAP).
&  AND.TFIELD(A+1,B).LT.TEMP_MELT))THEN
```

Comment: See https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/805-4939/6j4m0vn6l/index.html

Comment: What is your question? Is anything wrong with your example? Any error messages? What is the suffix of your source file? At which columns do your lines start?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In FORTRAN 77, column 6 is the continuation column.  Any non-blank, non-zero there means the line is a continuation of the one above:

```
C23456789 123456789 123456789 123456789 123456789
      IF((TEMP_PT.GT.TEMP_EVAP.
     &  AND.TFIELD(A+1,B).LT.TEMP_EVAP).OR.   
     &  ((TEMP_PT.GT.TEMP_MELT.AND.TEMP_PT.LT.TEMP_EVAP).
     &  AND.TFIELD(A+1,B).LT.TEMP_MELT))THEN
```

Comment: Just to remark, there is a limit to the number of continuations (in F77 the standard limit is 19, compilers may support more). It would be strange to reach that limit with an IF statement, but it is frequently reached in DATA statements when initializing large arrays.